# Отображение модулей в проекте yii2

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте.

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в админской части проекта отображались модули, подключенные в проекте. Их можно было их включать и отключать с помощью щелчка по кнопке.

Вот мы добавляем модуль в проект в папку module. Обновляем страницу, этот модуль появился у нас в списке подключенных модулей. После чего мы можем его отключить или включить обратно.

Как это будет лучше сделать и реализовать?

Шаблон приложения basic, подключен adminLTE.

Comment: Можно парсить composer.json и выдавать модули, которые в нём прописаны, как вариант

Comment: @AlMr хм. Хороший вариант.

Comment: @AlMr но хотя. Если мы будет использовать через composer.json, то тут мы сможет отслеживать только авторские модули, выложенные на каком либо ресурсе. А если мы написали сам модуль,тогда ведь не выйдет. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Верно. В `composer.json` содержатся только скаченные модули. Которые располагаются в папке `vendor`. Если у Вас имеются и собственные локальные модули то их нужно отслеживать отдельно и как-то иначе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему найдя ответ на гитхабе.

[Решение](https://github.com/bmsrox/yii2-module-autoloader)

Смысл заключается в том, чтобы создать событие, которое будет добавлять автоматически в массив модули проекта и выводить в виде списка.

Для этого в каждом модуле нужно будет добавить конфигурацию и отдельный класс, чтобы можно было передать в массив данные о модуле.

Пример реализации приведен в ссылке.

Единственное с чем возникла проблема, так это с расположением файлов config.php и class Events , они должны расположены не в корневой папке для всех модулей, а в корневой папке самого модуля.

Надеюсь найденная мною информацию кому-то да поможет. )

Comment: @defaultlocale Спасибо за замечание. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Стало лучше, спасибо!